# Is there anyway way to transfer .psd files from a windows machine to a mac without exposing other files?

Tags: windows, ftp, photoshop, mac

I need to transfer photoshop files back and forth from my computer (mac) to a girls computer (windows) that I'm working with. The only problem with FTP is whoever is it exposes other files on the other persons computer. Plus with FTP both computers have to be connected in order to transfer. Is there any way to get around this?

note: I tried just emailing the files in gmail, but the files are rendered in the browser. when what I really need is to import the files into photoshop and edit them.

Comment: You don't seem to be using email attachments and FTP correctly. A properly configured SFTP server (since FTP isn't secure) will not expose any files you don't want it to. Likewise, Gmail definitely allows you to download attachments. You just have to click the "download" link instead of the "view" link.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté You're absolutely right. I was using my Built in mail app to view my gmail and for some reason there's no download link.

Comment: I think some email clients do that by default for images. If there's no option to download it, you could always bypass the feature by zipping or RARing your files. But Dropbox _is_ a really handy way to share files for collaborations. I much prefer using it or the file sharing features on project managers like ManyMoon over emailing back and forth.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is [dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com), it allows you to transfer the files without exposing them to the internet and, as it downloads the files to your local machine and performs a continuous differential sync, you get to work with them as if they're on a folder on your local drive (which they are).

*Dropbox do have some interesting terms of service and don't have the best reputation as a result, so read the TOS and be careful.*

Comment: http://sparkleshare.org/ is open source and could be a good alternative to dropbox.